# How to update the value of nested assigns in LiveView

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

I’m trying to use nested assigns but cannot find a way to update its values…
Imagine I have this:

```
def mount(socket) do
    socket = assign(socket, state: [value1: "20", value2: "50"])
    {:ok, socket} 
end
```

How do I update the value here?

```
def handle_event("dec", _params, socket) do
    socket = assign(socket, state[:value1], "1")
    {:noreply, socket}
end
```

How do I reference/represent that nested key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Kernel.update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#update_in/3) is your friend here.

```rb
state = [value1: "20", value2: "50"]
update_in state, [:value1], & &1 <> "updated"
#⇒ [value1: "20updated", value2: "50"]
```

*Sidenote:* this question has nothing to do with [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework).

Comment: Thank you! I've removed the "phoenix-framework" tag.